# Find clusters of bacteria

Tags: python

I have to find all clusters of bacteria that are connected (4-connectivity) in a Python program. The input is a file that looks like this:

```
                     ###
                     #####
                     #######
                    #######
                     ######
                     ###### ##
                     ####  #####
                       ## ######        ####
                    #    ######       ####
                  ###  ##########    #####
                #######  ####  ##   ######
                ######### ##   #      #####
      #           ####   ###          ###
     #####        ####    #     ##     ##
     #####                    ######    #
    ######                   ########
     ####                     ########
                              #######
                              #######
```

NOTE: Clusters that are adjacent to the edge of the grid cannot be counted

This file is saved in the form of a 2D array in my class. I wrote this function to find all the clusters but it creates to many clusters (22 instead of 5). Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

My code:

```
def findAll(self):
    self.colonies = [set()]
    for i in range(len(self.grid)):
        for j in range(len(self.grid[i])):
            if self.grid[i][j] == "#":
                added = False
                count = 0
                for k in self.colonies:
                    if self.checkNeighbours((i, j), k):
                        k.add((i, j))
                        added = True
                    count += 1
                if not added:
                    self.colonies.append({(i, j)})

def checkNeighbours(self, pos, current):
    return ((pos[0] + 1, pos[1]) in current
            or (pos[0] - 1, pos[1]) in current
            or (pos[0], pos[1] + 1) in current
            or (pos[0], pos[1] - 1) in current)
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't 6 bacteria in this image?

Comment: There are indeed 6 bacteria but I forgot to mention that bacteria that are adjacent to the edge of the grid cannot be counted. So this makes the number of bacteria 5.

Comment: Oh i see, those are clusters. And the bottom cluster should be ignored? If so, you might want to add it in the question itself instead of here, so that readers can see it easily.

Comment: I will certainly do that. I'm sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: Can you post the code for checkNeighbours?

Comment: could you also comment a bit on your algorithmic strategy? Are you trying to calculate the SCCs?

Comment: Your issue is called [connected-component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) and the easiest algorithm is in two passes (because you could start two components on one row before you can see they are connected so you'd need to fuse them afterwards).

Comment: I added the checkNeighbours-method. And I will take a look at the connected component labeling. Thank you very much so far.

Comment: Could it be that 22 is the number of 4-connected pixels which is what you're calculating?

Comment: Besides the single pass issue, you should initialize your colonies with an empty list (the first empty set will stay empty). And what is `count` supposed to count? Right now it will count the components for each '#' pixel, but you could as well directly use `len(self.colonies)`.

Comment: Oops, yes indeed. Count was something I used to debug my code. You can ignore it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you had is that from the moment you formed two clusters, you couldn't join them. Even if eventually the two clusters were meant to be joined by the addition of intermediate nodes.

This can be solved by an application of a [union-find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). An unoptimized python version is:

```
s = """\
                     ###                    \
                     #####                  \
                     #######                \
                    #######                 \
                     ######                 \
                     ###### ##              \
                     ####  #####            \
                       ## ######        ####\
                    #    ######       ####  \
                  ###  ##########    #####  \
                #######  ####  ##   ######  \
                ######### ##   #      ##### \
      #           ####   ###          ###   \
     #####        ####    #     ##     ##   \
     #####                    ######    #   \
    ######                   ########       \
     ####                     ########      \
                              #######       \
                              #######       \
"""
representatives = {i: i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c == '#'}
nrows, ncols = 19, 44

def neighbours(idx):
    i, j = divmod(idx, ncols)
    if i > 0: yield idx - ncols
    if i < nrows - 1: yield idx + ncols
    if j > 0: yield idx - 1
    if j < ncols - 1: yield idx + 1

def representative(a):
    while representatives[a] != a: a = representatives[a]
    return a

def join(a, b):
    repr_a, repr_b = representative(a), representative(b)
    if repr_a != repr_b: representatives[repr_a] = repr_b

for idx in representatives:
    for n in neighbours(idx):
        if s[n] == '#': join(idx, n)

cluster_count = len(set(map(representative, representatives)))
```

Result:

```
6
```

You could also have created also a graph and used [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find the connected components. The advantage of the above method is that it's incremental and you can update easily the clusters with the addition of new points.

Answer (score 4):

Detecting features is easily done with the [scipy ndimage measurements](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.measurements) module. It has the added advantage of speed, if you go this way.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label, find_objects

q = np.genfromtxt('bacteria.txt', dtype='S1', comments=':', delimiter=1)
arr = (q == b'#')  # convert to boolean mask because ' ' evaluates to True

labelled, num_features = label(arr)

def count_edge_objects(labelled):
    hulls = find_objects(labelled)
    nbr_edgeobjects = 0
    for rowslice, colslice in hulls:
        if (rowslice.start == 0 or rowslice.stop == labelled.shape[0] or
            colslice.start == 0 or colslice.stop == labelled.shape[1]):
            nbr_edgeobjects += 1
    return nbr_edgeobjects

print('{} objects'.format(num_features - count_edge_objects(labelled)))
# output: 
# 4 objects
```

In the dataset you've shown there are 2 objects near the edge: the one at the top and the one at the bottom. Remark that I'm currently assuming the dataset has an equal amount of characters on each line (if not, check out the `missing_values` option of `np.genfromtxt`)

Comment: Nice! You could also use `(np.unique(np.r_[labelled[0], labelled[-1], labelled[:, 0], labelled[:, -1]]) > 0).sum()` as an alternative to `count_edge_objects(labelled)`.